# Cambiar strings tomando como referencia diccionarios

Tags: python, funciones, revisión-de-código, programación-funcional, diccionarios

Para plantear mi pregunta correctamente, pondré un poco de código "contextual". Desafortunadamente, tuve que acudir a ver las soluciones de un par de ejercicios porque no me quedó en claro qué había que hacer y cómo funciona el código. Espero puedan orientarme.
En primer lugar, creo un diccionario que tenga como llaves los números del 0 al 26 y como valores las letras a-z incluyendo el espacio en blanco "". Aquí no tuve problemas y creo que es sencillo.

```
import string
string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + " "
letters= dict(enumerate(alphabet,0))
```

Aquí surge mi primera duda: ¿Cómo "razona" el código para encoding? ¿Cómo es que cambia keys y valores y les da otra numeración?

```
encryption_key=3
encoding = {letters[i]:(encryption_key+ i)%27 for i in range(27)}
```

Teniendo encoding, vamos a cifrar el siguiente mensaje:

```
message = "hi my name is caesar"
```

Esta función cambia las letras por números según los valores en encoding:

```
def caesar(message, encryption_key):
    f_string = "".join(str(encoding.get(i)) for i in message)
    return f_string

encoded_message= caesar(message, encryption_key=3)
print(encoded_message)
```

Por su parte, esta cambia las letras de "message" por las letras correspondientes de encoding pero tomando como referencia el diccionario letters:

```
def caesar(message, encryption_key): 
    f_string = "".join([letters[encoding[i]] for i in message])
    return f_string


encoded_message= caesar(message, encryption_key=3)
print(encoded_message)
```

Básicamente, me interesa saber cuál es la lógica que sigue el código en ambas funciones para alcanzar el resultado deseado, ya que en ambos casos intenté hacer aproximaciones utilizado "for", "while" "if" e incluso "in" sin ningún éxito. 
Agradezco mucho cualquier orientación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ir paso a paso:

1. `alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + " "`

   Obtenemos una cadena con las letras minúsculas de la "a" a la "z" (abecedario ingles) + espacio.
2. `letters= dict(enumerate(alphabet,0))`

   Crea un diccionario a partir de un objeto `enumerate`, para cada ítem (carácter) de la cadena retorna una tupla con un un contador empezando desde 0 en este caso y el carácter corespondiente. El primer elemento de la tupla (contador) hace de clave y el segundo (carácter) de valor del diccionario.
3. `encryption_key=3
    encoding = {letters[i]:(encryption_key+ i)%27 for i in range(27)}`

   Lo primero, con `encoding = {letters[i]:i for i in range(27)}` crearíamos un diccionario igual a `letters` pero invirtiendo claves y valores (recorremos que las claves que van de 0 a 26).

   En este punto hay que recordar como funciona el cifrado César, es un cifrado por sustitución que se consigue simplemente moviendo  cada letra un determinado número de espacios en el alfabeto. En este ejemplo se usa un desplazamiento de tres espacios.

   Debemos rotar el alfabeto, en este caso la "a" será el tercer carácter, la "b" el cuarto, etc. Esto se puede hacer simplemente sumado 3 al al valor, pero... ¿Qué pasa con las ultimas letras?.  En este caso (3 desplazamientos) la 'y 'debe pasar a ser el primer carácter (valor 0), la 'z' el segundo (valor 1) y el espacio el tercero (valor 2). Si sumáramos 3 simplemente tendrían valores 29, 30 y 31 respectivamente, lo cual no queremos.

   En este punto es donde entra en juego el operador módulo o resto de la división (`%`). La [aritmética modular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aritm%C3%A9tica_modular) nos permite crear un anillo. Imagina un reloj tradicional, las horas siempre están en entre las 1 y las 12, cuando llegamos a las 12 volvemos a empezar por la 1. Es decir, si son las 3 y sumamos 26 horas moviendo la manecilla del reloj obtendremos que son las 5, no "las 29". Esto es porque se aplica aritmética modular sin saberlo, lo que hacemos es no solo sumar, sino obtener el resto de la divisíón entre 12 de esa suma:

   > - 3 +26 = 29
   > - 29 dividido entre 12 = 2 y resto 5.

   No se si con el ejemplo se pilla el concepto, pero con el cifrado César hacemos lo mismo solo que nuestro "reloj" no es de 12 horas, sino de 27. Lo que conseguimos es rotar todas las letras pero manteniendo su posición dentro del rango 0-26 en todo momento. Esto es lo único importante realmente del código. El resto es simplemente obtener valores de los diccionarios usando sus claves.
4. Primera función:

   ```
    def caesar(message, encryption_key):
        f_string = "".join(str(encoding.get(i)) for i in message)
        return f_string
   ```

   Simplemente toma como argumentos el mensaje y la clave de encriptación, que en realidad no es más que el número de desplazamientos que se aplican al abecedario.

   `(str(encoding.get(i)) for i in message)` es un generador que retorna por cada carácter del mensaje (claves en `encoding`) su valor correspondiente en el diccionario `encoding`. Para la "h" retorna su valor, "10", para la "i" retorna "11", para el espacio retorna "2", etc.

   Básicamente lo que conseguimos es obtener el orden que cada carácter tiene en el abecedario desplazado 3 posiciones. `str.join` se limita a recorrer el iterable y retornar una cadena con el string intercalado entre cada ítem:

   ```
   >>> l = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
   >>> s = "-".join(l)
   >>> s
   "1-2-3-4"
   ```

   La función seria equivalente a:

   ```
   def caesar(message,  encriptation_key):
       f_string = ""
       for char in message:
           f_string =  f_string + str(encoding.get(char))
       print(f_string)
   ```
5. Segunda función:

   ```
       def caesar(message, encryption_key): 
           f_string = "".join([letters[encoding[i]] for i in message])
           return f_string
   ```

   La primera función no sirve de mucho, nos retorna los lugares que ocuparían las letras de `message` si desplazamos el alfabeto 3 posiciones pero no nos retorna el mensaje encriptado. Esta función es una extensión de la anterior. Simplemente hace lo que la anterior, solo que una vez obtenida la posición en el nuevo alfabeto, usa esa posición para buscar la letra correspondiente en el alfabeto original sin desplazar (diccionario `letters`). Para la la primera letra es la "h", esta ocupa la posición 8 en el alfabeto real, la desplazamos 3 posiciones, por lo que pasa a ocupar la posición 11. La letra 11 en el alfabeto sin desplazar es la "k". Este es el proceso que sigue esta función, obtener la posición de cada carácter en el alfabeto desplazado (`encodig`) y usar esa posición para obtener la letra correspondiente en el alfabeto sin desplazar (`letters`).

   La función es equivalente a:

   ```
   def caesar2(message,  encryption_key):
       f_string = ""
       for char in message:
           posicion =  encoding.get(char)
           f_string = f_string + letters[posicion]
       return f_string
   ```

Esto como siempre me ha quedado muy largo...Creo que se entiende todo, puede que la aritmética modular sea lo más complicado, pero si miras el enlace y buscas información en Google podrás aclararte si te quedan dudas.

Comment: Gracias. Totalmente claro y explicativo.